# ESP8266 GPIO pin improvement

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, industrial

Is it possible to make this connection to an ESP8266 pin?

I saw this at Ruggeduino and tried to implement it for the ESP8266.

Below is the schematic:

[image]

Here's my reference:

[image]

This type of diode:

[image]

Here's my whole schematic:

[image]

Here's the PCB looks like:

TOP SIDE

[image]

BOT SIDE

[image]

Comment: Please try to be a bit more specific about the diodes. As is it I don't seen anything strange except for the diode. If the wrong kind is used you may pull too much current from the GPIO. What is the exact model you plan to use ?

Comment: i've been update my question to give some details,

Comment: What are you intending to do with that circuit? Also that's a 5.1V zener. The 3.3V IO on ESP would be toast long before the zener starts to conduct.

Comment: just want to make io more safe, i seen at ruggeduino ( arduino industrial use )  website for this schematic and try to implemented to esp8266

Comment: I wouldn’t be using the ruggeduino as the gold standard. Realistically, you shouldn’t be running gpio out into the real world without some form of signal conditioning. That is where you’d add the protection, not right on the gpio.

Comment: kindly advice how to make esp8266 as industrial standard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That topology works for 5V and above, but 3.3V Zener diodes are pretty sloppy.  They have very soft knee and they vary a lot on when they will start conducting.
A better approach at this and lower voltages would be to use two Schottky diodes connected to the power rails.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKIE4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, so i just need to add more diode like your schematic right ?... and is it okey to use same type diode ?

Comment: Yes, use the same diode part number in both positions.

Comment: sir, i've been upload my complete schematic, if you're not busy, would you check if there have somethings wrong. thanks.

Comment: @RizkisWalker That is way too tiny of a schematic to read.  Upload it the way you did the first schematic, where I can click and get a larger view.

Comment: the picture now can be enlarge

Comment: Not knowing the entire application, it looks pretty good.  FET Q2 may be backwards if it is supposed to gate VBAT and VBUS.  The internal diode doesn't allow turning off VBAT.  If it's for polarity protection, then it's okay as is.

Comment: thankyou so much, i just want to make a good esp8266 module, is there any circuit at the schematic need to be update ?

Comment: Where is the ground plane and stitching? This is a pcb with 2.4GHz and high speed digital. The pcb is critical to the correct operation. I’d suggest you use a module.

Comment: not yet, i have plan to make copper area for grounding at top and bottom side. is it ok to to this ?, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Kartman, i've update the PCB could you plesae check it ?

Comment: You’ve still got a lot of work to do. Do Espressif give a pcb layout example?

Comment: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf, only guideline

Comment: @RizkisWalker Check out section **1.6.1. General Principles of PCB Layout Design** from your link.